# Webpack with babel-loader doesn't recognize Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I am using webpack and trying to leverage an existing React component library written in TS.

However, with the settings below, the webpack is giving 'unexpected Token' error. I copied the problematic code to babel online transpiler https://babeljs.io/repl/ but it is not showing any error.

I am very new to React development, any criticism/questions/answers are welcomed.

Thanks!

This is my ***webpack.config.js***

```
var path = require("path")
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')


module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './app/static/js/index'
  ],

  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./app/static/bundles/'),
      filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
      publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/static/bundles/',
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: ["babel-loader?presets[]=es2015,presets[]=react"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          configFileName: './tsconfig.json'
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.css']
  }
}
```

My entry point file ***index.js***:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';

interface IDemoState {
  value             ?: string;
}

class Test extends React.Component<{}, IDemoState> {
  state: IDemoState = {
    value         : 'general'
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('tabnav'));
```

***Package.json***

```
{
  "name": "djangoproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Django Project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --progress --colors",
    "build-production": "webpack --config webpack.prod.config.js --progress --colors",
    "watch": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Django"
  ],
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "adp-css-framework": "^1.5.3",
    "adp-react-components": "^1.4.3",
    "adp-react-icons": "^1.16.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "ts-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "typescript": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.0"
  }
}
```

If I run **npm run watch**, I got this error:

```
ERROR in ./app/static/js/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: xxxxx./app/static/js/index.js: Unexpected token (10:20)

   8 |
   9 | class Test extends React.Component<{}, IDemoState> {
> 10 |   state: IDemoState = {
     |                     ^
  11 |     value         : 'general'
  12 |   }
  13 | }

 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 webpack/hot/only-dev-se
rver ./app/static/js/index
```

Comment: try renaming your .js files to .tsx

Comment: Tried that too, then a new problem is happening as it looks like ts-loader is not recognizing babel/jsx syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The problem finally goes away after I changed the ts-loader to awesome-typescript-loader and write everything in a tsx file.

Comment: `awesome-typescript-loader` is also suggested by Microsoft Official Documentation :)

Comment: Confirmed, it appears - as best I can tell at least - that babel-loader refuses to process anything that's not in the `src` folder, even if explicitly told to do so. That is it'll take it if it satisfies the test, but then it won't actually compile the TS or TSX. Awesome-Typescript-Loader appears happy to compile from any location though.